# Rigid Body Dynamics - How do objects move in loops?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I have been attempting to simulate the motion of a (heavily) simplified model of a rocket using MATLAB's Simulink, but I am not seeing behavior that I expect (intuitively, and I am very open to being wrong) when tracking the translational motion with respect to the inertial/earth axes.

The key component of this model is the 6DOF (Euler Angle) block from Simulink Aerospace Libraries, which has the same rigid body dynamic equations I am familiar with from literature: https://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/6dofeulerangles.html

I've been trying to isolate the source of the motion that doesn't make sense to me and have removed the effect of both gravity and aerodynamic drag, as well as set my engine gimbal angles to zero. Therefore, the rocket experiences thrust only along its axial direction. This, predictably, produces no turning whatsoever. If I then introduce a constant yaw rate using the block parameters (NOT with a gimbal angle that produces a moment) I would expect the body to move through space in the **XYe** plane to trace a circle, returning to its starting position and orientation every 2pi radians of rotation in yaw.

However, instead what I find is that for every 4pi radians of rotation in yaw, the body moves half that angular distance about its center of rotation:

[image]

This leads me to conclude that the orientation of the rocket at certain key points is as shown on the left, while I would expect to see something more like the image on the right:

[image] [image]

I've obtained the positions in the earth plane by extracting the velocity vector in earth axes and integrating, as suggested by many tutorials and the literature. I've also dug into the 6DOF block itself in the library, and the calculations it uses align directly with the equations of motion I find in literature.

Is my intuition incorrect and this is actually the motion we would expect?

Further, if I remove the fixed yaw rate and instead introduce a gimbal angle (and thus angular acceleration) in the same direction, the motion becomes an even more extreme (but still consistent with the above) path: [image: even more extreme]

Again, I am open to the idea that my intuition is very incorrect. If this is the case, the followup question I have is why is the rate of rotation of the body always twice that of the rate of rotation of the body about its center of rotation in the translational plane? Is this a feature of rigid body dynamics and if so, how do we explain motion throughout a loop?

Apologies if I've butchered the nomenclature.

Comment: If you ignore gravity and drag forces, to produce circular motion the applied force must always be directed to the *center* of the circle. That follows from the basic (high school level) equations for uniform circular motion.

Comment: Due to there being a constant rate of angular rotation, some portion of the applied force is directed toward the center of the circle. This follows from the tangential velocity expression found on this page, near the bottom: https://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/6dofeulerangles.html of omega cross V. Similar effects are found from gimbaling the engine in a direction, which also produce moments to create the angular acceleration.